# Android context memory leak via activity private member

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Please clarify is code listed below would lead to context memory leak? Thanks

```
public class HelperClass {
     private Context context;

     public HelperClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
     }
     public void myHelperMethod() {
    // uses this.context
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private HelperClass helper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         helper = new HelperClass(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  What you want to beware of is a reference to the context/activity that remains after the activity has been destroyed.  A device rotation is an example of an action that would cause the current activity to be destroyed by Android.

In this case, your activity is the only thing that holds a reference to your helper class.  Thus when the activity is destroyed, there will be no more existing references.

If however your activity class defined the reference to the helper as a static, then that would cause a memory leak.  The static reference would remain even after the activity instance was destroyed.  The helper class, which holds a reference to the activity, would then prevent the activity instance from being garbaged collected.